# Only execute a function once in a given amount of time

Tags: javascript, lodash, debouncing

I have an api request that is called multiple times in a given amount of time. More specifically this request is for refreshing the user token, so it's called on every request, which adds up pretty quickly. I would like to create a function that tells the function not to run for a given amount of seconds. I have tried using lodash debounce but I can't get it to work.

```
let debounceRefresh;

debounceRefresh = debounce(() => {
  api.request(){
  });
}, 1000);

debounceRefresh();
```

Am I executing this wrong? Is it possible to do?

Comment: Don't you mean to `throttle` it?

Comment: I'm looking into throttling right now, I am new to the concept

Comment: `api.request(){});` looks like a syntax error. What are you really doing?

Comment: Where and how often are you calling `debounceRefresh();`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely need `throttle` for the job.

```js
// in this example we invoke a fn for a period of 10 sec, invoking it 2 times a second, but we can perceive that the original function is only invoked at most once per 2 seconds according to the parameter below:

var TOTAL_TIME_TO_RUN = 10000; // 10 sec
var THROTTLE_INTERVAL = 2000; // <= adjust this number to see throttling in action
var INVOCATION_INTERVAL = 500; // 0.5 sec

// regular fn
var punchClock = function punchClock() {
  console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ' - call api');
};

// wrap it and supply interval representing minimum delay between invocations
var throttledPunchClock = _.throttle(punchClock, THROTTLE_INTERVAL);

// set up looping
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("attempting call api");
  throttledPunchClock()
}, INVOCATION_INTERVAL);

// run the demo
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(intervalId), 10000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  var TOTAL_TIME_TO_RUN = 10000; // 10 sec
  var THROTTLE_INTERVAL = 2000; // < = adjust this number to see throttling in action
  var INVOCATION_INTERVAL = 500; // 0.5 sec
</pre>
```

Snippet from [github](https://gist.github.com/ICEDLEE337/a29a2c4233c92e529b0623cad4310e93)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a timeout?

```
const myTimeout = setTimeout(debounceRefresh, 1000);
```

If the function is called again, you can clear the timeout and reset it

`clearTimeout(myTimeout);`

Why don't you use a different listener? Perhaps when data is received?

Comment: I've tried that, it's not working as intended.